# Can not install ggplot for Python on Windows 7, Anaconda 5

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda, python-ggplot

I am trying to install ggplot for Python, see below:

[image]

All three commands return error messages.  The first one is perhaps the most elaborate:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\AKONST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-y54n7lcl-uninstall\\users\\akonstantinidis\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 795, in install
    requirement.commit_uninstall()
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 767, in commit_uninstall
    self.uninstalled.commit()
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 142, in commit
    rmtree(self.save_dir)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\AKONST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-y54n7lcl-uninstall\\users\\akonstantinidis\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
```

I am not sure what these messages imply and how they should be dealt with.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the installation as administrator.Right click the anoconda prompt and select run as administrator and then run the installation.You will need an admin user to do this.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to reinstall Anaconda?  What do you mean by "right click the anaconda prompt"?  What is this anaconda prompt? I am running the command through Jupyter notebook. !pip install -U ggplot

Comment: When you install anaconda you will get anaconada prompt program.Just check whether you have the anaconda prompt program.Then use command conda install -c r r-ggplot2 there.For anaconda always try to use this kind of installation for packages.You can search the anaconda.org to find the commands to use install different packages in anaconda

Comment: I have added screenshot of taking the anaconda prompt